# How to get the file object in `request.data` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, file-upload, django-file-upload

1. Upload a tar file.
2. How to get the file object in `request.data`?

```py
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False, url_path='upload-album')
    def upload_album(self, request):
        # Upload one tar file.
        logging.error("----> request.data = {}".format(request.data))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get file object in `request.FILES`.
`request.FILES` is dictionary like object containing all uploaded files. You can access your file object by its name, like this: `request.FILES['my-file-name']`

For example, if you want to log filename::

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False, url_path='upload-album')
    def upload_album(self, request):
        # Upload one tar file.
        logging.error("----> Uploaded file name = {}".format(request.FILES['my-file-name'].name))
```

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.
But when I print the request.FILES, you can see that it is <MultiValueDict: {}>

[Print Log]
root:----> request.FILES --> = <MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: Thanks, I find the answer finally.
I should to upload file by Multipart/form-data.